# Why is only one of my media queries not working?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm using multiple media queries for a website, and the largest (min-width:1201px) is the only one that is not implementing any changes. Here are the queries that I've used, typed exactly as seen in my CSS, and in this exact order:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {}

@media only screen and (min-width:480px) {}

@media only screen (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {}

@media only screen (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px) {}

@media screen (min-width: 1201px) {}
```

I have included the meta tag in the head of the index.html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Another thing I found odd, is in the index.html I have applied media queries with different sized pictures for the background cover photo, and the one I used there with the min-width: 1200 worked.

I'm really hoping one of you could pinpoint what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Not all those queries are working. I think this is what you are after.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) {}
@media only screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width: 767px) {}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {}
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px) {}
@media screen and (min-width: 1201px) {}
```

see it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/e7wdmca4/1/

Comment: Just to add to what @kolsyrad said i would change the first query to media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {}
that way it would apply to all the small screens up  tp 479px width :)

Comment: @Saa_keetin good mention, I'll leave it as is in case there's some special case for being below 320px :)

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'll give it a try and hope that it works :) I'm rather new at this, so getting help is always good @kolsyrad

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an "and" in the last query:
@media screen and (min-width: 1201px) {}